# Cannot change swappiness default from 60 to 0 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, swap

So I've read several related threads and there seems to be no answer.

I have an old laptop, with a Dual Core 1.7 GHz processor and added 2 GB of RAM, with a 30 GB partition for Ubuntu 12.04 and the remaining for Windows XP.

I want to change the default swappiness from 60 to 0.

When I start the computer and run `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` in Terminal I get the value 60.

I have no problems changing it to 0 with `sudo sysctl vm.swappines=0`

I have tried several times changing the file `/etc/sysctl` by adding at the end

```
#
# vm.swappiness=0
```

But every time I restart my computer the value given by `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` is still 60.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is not being applied because it's commented, instead of:

```
# vm.swappiness=0
```

It should read:

```
vm.swappiness=0
```

Try that and reboot.

Comment: Thanks darent, that did the job. The final lines of my `/etc/sysctl` are now

`# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1

vm.swappiness=0`

Comment: You can mark the answer as solved if it helped you. Another alternative solution is to comment the swap line in /etc/fstab but that would remove the computer ability to go into hibernation mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have mine set like this:

```
#
# Decrease swap usage to a workable level
vm.swappiness=10
# Improve cache management
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

I guess you can just use "0" instead of my "10", but this should work.

Comment: Thanks natkoui, but I have already fixed this with darent's answer. Very successful first question.

Comment: Also, you can vote other solutions up. I just up-voted this one because it also works.